# Search Results for how do i add extra or custom fonts into a marketo form

Tags: css, api, fonts, marketo

We have a marketo form and want to use custom fonts. Does the marketo api alow this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google fonts and the standard fonts.

https://docs.marketo.com/display/DOCS/Change+the+Form+Font+Family

Comment: Thanks for your comment - It is fairly obvious that you can use the standard google fonts. I would not have come to stackoverflow if it was this simple. Google fonts does not include all fonts that we want to use.

Comment: Using custom fonts (like one you made yourself) requires you put the call to that CSS in the template or page. Some developer resources for forms: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/

Answer (score -1):

You can add custom CSS to a Marketo form at the form level. You'll want to add something like:

```
.mktoForm {
font-family:"YourFont", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; 
}

.mktoForm input[type=radio] + label:before
{
  content: "";  
  position:absolute;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;  
  margin-left:-1.5em;
  line-height:1em;
  font-family: "Your Font", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px 0px #ccc;
  background-color:#fff;
```

(Instructions here on where to add this code - https://community.marketo.com/MarketoArticle?id=kA050000000LHXhCAO )

However, be sure to also add the font information to the page CSS, then be sure all CSS for your form on the page CSS directs to the right font. Example:

```
form.lpeRegForm label {
    font-family: "Your Font", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

form.lpeRegForm input[type="text"], form.lpeRegForm select, form.lpeRegForm  textarea {
    border: 1px solid #D9D8D9;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Your Font", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The new forms 2.0 has different CSS.